# map address mail.example.com to sendmail port 25 on example.com

Tags: sendmail, subdomain, mx-record

I have a A record for `example.com` mapped to an ec2 linux instance binded to an elastic ip where I run an apache webserver and where I want to run the sendmail mail server too.

I have currently set the `MX record to example.com` which is not good practice I believe.

I want to do the right thing and have the `MX record as mail.example.com` or smtp.example.com

If I change my MX record what will map the `mail.` part?

What do I have to do so that mail.example.com means actually example.com:25 Is there a host file on my server that I must set?

Answer (score 5):

> I have currently set the MX record to example.com which is not good practice I believe.

You're wrong. You can set the MX record to whatever you want as long as there's an SMTP server there that's willing to accept mail for your domain.

---

> I want to do the right thing and have the MX record as `mail.example.com` or `smtp.example.com`

You can certainly do that if it makes you happy. It's no more "right" or "wrong" though.

---

> If I change my MX record what will map the mail. part?

You need to create a DNS entry for `mail.example.com`.
Best practices dictate that this should be an `A` (or `AAAA`) record.

---

> What do I have to do so that mail.example.com means actually example.com:25

DNS and MX records have ***ABSOLUTELY NOTHING TO DO WITH PORT NUMBERS***.
An MX record simply says "when sending mail to this domain (`example.com`) talk to this server (`mail.example.com`). The MTA sending the message decides what port to use.

Comment: Okay, so if I keep thing that way which is not a bad idea afaiu, I could still connect to my sendmail client on example.com using the mail.example.com address?

Answer (score 1):

Just creat an A record for mail.example.com, point to IP address of example.com, i.e:

```
example.com      --> 1.2.3.4
mail.example.com --> 1.2.3.4
```

Then creat a MX record which point to mail.example.com. All work will be fine.

Comment: create a A record for mail.example.com ? I have doubt about that.